# Error Hide keyboard before move to next controller Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to hide keyboard before move to next controller. Also implement self.view.enditing(true) in viewWillDisapear . But keybard not hide how to hide this?

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if textField == tagTxt{
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            let interstControlle = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InterestViewController") as! InterestViewController
            interstControlle.PContId = "InterestViewController"
            interstControlle.delegate = self
            if tagsID.count > 0{
                interstControlle.PTagsID = tagsID
            }
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(interstControlle, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   if textField == tagTxt{
     return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Swift 3:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
     if textField == tagTxt{
        return false
     }
     return true
}
```

Comment: How to implement this into Swift?

Answer (score 1):

You have to `return false` before textfield get active. We can see difference by name `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidBeginEditing`.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == tagTxt {
        //Your code to move in next view
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```